# Is every surjective holomorphic self-map on a compact complex manifold finite-to-one?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds

I have already asked this question on [stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3918462/is-surjective-holomorphic-self-map-on-compact-complex-manifold-finite), but I didn’t get any answer.

Let $X$ be a compact connected complex manifold.

> Let $f:X \to X$ be a **surjective** holomorphic map. Is it true that $f$ is a finite map (i.e., every point has finitely many preimages)?

If $X$ is one dimensional then the answer to the above question is yes. If $X$ is a complex projective space then the answer is again  yes.

If we don’t assume surjectivity then we can easily construct non-constant,  non-finite self-maps (just consider the product manifold and $f$ to be projection on one of the coordinates).

Comment: In this paper

https://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/1024.pdf

Gromov claims that 

"More generally, if $V$ and $V'$ are complex (not necessarily compact or Kaehler) manifolds of equal dimensions and their even Betti numbers are flnite and
equal (i.e. $b_{2 i} = b'_{2i}$ ) then every proper surjective holomorphic map $f \colon V \to V'$ is finite-to-one ", see p. 223

Comment: In particular, this applies to your case.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Thanks for the reference! It answers my question. Question: what is a counterexample when $f:X \to Y$ is a surjective holomorphic map between distinct compact manifolds? Thanks again!

Comment: Well, take the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$ at one point.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Thank you! I missed this easy example of blow up.

Comment: Well, Gromov just states the result mentioned by Francesco Polizzi, he doesn't prove it. It would be nice if one can actually prove Gromov's claim.

Comment: @user48958 Yes! That would be great. Please let me know if you have any idea about the proof.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Do you know any reference where I can find the proof (at least in the case of self maps of compact manifolds)?

Comment: I added a sketch of proof

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me give a sketch of proof for Gromov's claim in the case where $X$ is Kähler. More precisely, let me prove the following ${}$

> **Proposition [G03, p.223].** Let $X$, $Y$ be two complex manifolds  (not necessarily compact) of the same dimension and having the same even Betti numbers. If $X$ is Kähler, then every proper surjective holomorphic map $f \colon X \to Y$ is finite-to-one.

*Proof.* By a result of Wells [**W74**, Theorem 3.1], the map $f \colon X \to Y$ induces an injection $$f^* \colon H^{r}(Y, \, \mathbb{C}) \to H^{r}(X, \, \mathbb{C})$$ for all $r$. Using the duality $$H_r(X, \, \mathbb{C})=\mathrm{Hom}(H^r(X, \, \mathbb{C}), \, \mathbb{C})$$ we infer that the induced map in homology $$f_* \colon H_{r}(X, \, \mathbb{C}) \to H_{r}(Y, \, \mathbb{C})$$ is surjective for all $r$.

If $f \colon X \to Y$ contracts a subvariety $Z$ of positive complex dimension $i$ to a point, then its fundamental class would give an element $[Z]$ in the kernel of $$f_* \colon H_{2i}(X, \, \mathbb{C}) \to H_{2i}(Y, \, \mathbb{C})$$

Now $Z$ is compact by the properness assumption and so, pairing with the Kähler
form on $X$, we can deduce that $[Z]$ is non-zero. Hence $b_{2i}(X) > b_{2i}(Y)$, contradiction. $\square$

**Remark.** The first version of this answer did not assume that $X$ was Kähler (in fact, Gromov does not make this assumption). However, if $X$ is not Kähler it may happen that the fundamental class of a compact subvariety of $X$ is homologically trivial, see the example of Hopf's surface given in Michael Albanese answer to **[MSE]**: in this case, $X$ contains a torus $C$ whose fundamental class $[C]$ is zero in $H_2(X, \, \mathbb{C})$, simply because the last group is trivial. So, if $X$ is not Kähler, the last part of the proof breaks down.

In fact, I do not know how to make the argument work without the Kähler assumption for $X$, so I asked a new [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377399/about-a-claim-by-gromov-on-proper-holomorphic-maps) about this problem.

**References.**

**[MSE]** https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1556561/456212

**[G03]** Gromov, M: [On the entropy of holomorphic maps](https://www.ihes.fr/%7Egromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/1024.pdf), *Enseign. Math.* II. Sér. **49**, No. 3-4, 217-235 (2003). [ZBL1080.37051](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1080.37051).

**[W74]** Wells, R. O. jun: [Comparison of de Rham and Dolbeault cohomology for proper surjective mappings](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1974.53.281), *Pac. J. Math.* **53**, 281-300 (1974). [ZBL0261.32005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0261.32005).

Comment: You should remove the word "proper" in the proposition:  since the domain $X$ is compact, properness is automatic.

Comment: I removed "compact", that is a too restrictive assumption. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the answer: actually, my argument requires that $X$ is Kähler. I would like to know whether this assumption is really necessary.

Comment: Yeh, I meant to ask how do you know that the class is nontrivial, but, occasionally, I have to sleep.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I think the manifolds $X$ and $Y$ have to be compact, otherwise your argument "Now Z is compact by the properness assumption and so, pairing with the Kähler
form on X, we can deduce that [Z] is non-zero." does not stand. You use the duality between homolgy and cohomolgy, but one of them has to be with compact supports. In other words, you want to use Stokes, but you might get boundary terms. So you can pair  a Kahler form and Z, but you cannot conclude that this pairing is zero.

Comment: @user48958 Compactness is not necessary. See M. Albanese answer in [MSE]

Comment: and also the comment of user98602 just below the question.

Comment: Nope, Z is compact, therefore it sits in a (co)homolgy with compact supprts. That is, you take it modulo boundaries of something with compact support. And then you can pair it with something that doesn't have compact support. But if you look at Z in a (co)homolgy with no restrictions, you can get anything you want. How should I put it, it's like you have two smooth functions $f$ and $g$ on a manifold $X$, and you say that $f\cdot g$ is always integrable on $X$. So the arguments of M. Albanese and user98602 are not correct.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that if $X$ is not compact, then there is no canonical map $H^*(X,{\mathbb R})\times H_*(X,{\mathbb R})\to {\mathbb R}$.

Comment: @user48958 I disagree. The restriction of the Kaehler form $\omega$ to $Z$ is Kaehler, so  $Z$ is a cpt. Kaehler manifold.  Thus,  if $\dim(Z)=k>0$, integrating $\omega^k$ over $[Z]$ we get $k! \mathrm{vol}(Z)$. This is Wirtinger's theorem, we are in the Kaehler world, that is much better than the ordinary manifold world. 

If $[Z]$ were $0$ in homology, we would get that the Riemannian volume of $Z$ is zero, which is a contradiction since $Z$ is positive-dimensional. See for instance Ballmann's book, Theorem 4.23 (2), p. 50.

http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/kaehler0609.pdf

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi So I have a problem with the following statement of yours: "If [Z] were 0 in homology, we would get that the Riemannian volume of Z is zero". Can you show me a proof of this fact? Ballmann's book, M. Albanese and user98602 do not provide a proof, they just state it as it is.

Comment: And by the way, in Ballmann's book, part of Theorem 4.23 is false if you drop the compactness assumption. In part 2 of the theorem, the author claims that the class of $\omega$ is nonzero in cohomology. However, this is false, take the manifold $M$ to be the complex ${\mathbb C}$, and $\omega$ to be $i\partial\bar \partial\vert z\vert ^2$. Then $\omega$ is Kahler, yet its class in cohomology is $0$.

Comment: @user48958 Let me answer to the second point you raised. One of the assumptions of part 2 of Ballman's theorem is the existence of a compact complex submanifold $N$ of dimension $k$ on $M$. If $M=\mathbb{C}^n$, there exists no such a submanifold unless $k=0$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi You're right, in the statement of Theorem 4.23 in Bellmann's book there is a compact submanifold $N$ in $M$. So my example does not apply to this situation.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi One question about your proof above: at some point you say that there is a duality $H_r(X,{\mathbb C})=Hom(H^r(X, {\mathbb C}), {\mathbb C})$, where $X$ is some complex manifold, not necessarily compact. Can you provide a reference for this statement? As far as I can tell, this sounds like the Poncare duality. However, in order to prove your claim, you have to have a non-degenerate bilinear application $H_r\times H^r\to {\mathbb C}$. What is is this map? Can you describe it explicitly?

Comment: No, this is not Poincaré, since the indices in homology and cohomology are equal. This is the Universal Coefficient Theorem: just note that the  $\textrm{Ext}^1$ group vanishes when $G$ is a field.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem

Comment: In fact, when the coefficient ring is a field this is called *Kronecker duality* and holds for every topological space with finite Betti numbers, not necessarily a manifold.