# About a claim by Gromov on proper holomorphic maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds

At p. 223 of his paper **[G03]**, Mikhail Gromov makes the following claim:

> Let $X$, $Y$ be two complex manifolds  (not necessarily compact or Kähler) of the same dimension and having the same even Betti numbers. Then every proper surjective holomorphic map $f \colon X \to Y$ is finite-to-one.

In my answer to MO question [377353](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377353/is-every-surjective-holomorphic-self-map-on-a-compact-complex-manifold-finite-to), I proposed a proof for this claim. However, checking the details I realized that such a proof requires that $X$ is Kähler.

In fact, the last step of my argument uses in an essential way the fact  that the fundamental class of a compact subvariety of $X$ is non-trivial in homology, and this is in general false when $X$ is not
Kähler. For instance, in his answer to **[MSE]**, Michael Albanese notices that the standard Hopf's surface $X$ contains a compact torus $C$ whose fundamental class $[C]$ is zero in $H_2(X, \, \mathbb{C})$, simply because the last group is trivial.

So, let me ask the

> **Question.** Is Gromov's claim true without the Kähler assumption for $X$? If so, what is a proof?

**References.**

**[G03]** Gromov, M: [On the entropy of holomorphic maps](https://www.ihes.fr/%7Egromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/1024.pdf), *Enseign. Math.* II. Sér. **49**, No. 3-4, 217-235 (2003). [ZBL1080.37051](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1080.37051).

**[MSE]** https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1556561/456212

Comment: Can a ruled subvariety have a homologically trivial fundamental class?

Comment: Good question. I do not know.

Comment: It is easy to see that the fundamental class of an irreducible curve in a smooth proper variety (which need not be Kahler) is always nontorsion, so the result holds in this case.

Comment: @naf: If your notion of "nontorsion" includes "nontrivial" then it would be false as the example of a smooth elliptic curve in a Hopf torus shows.

Comment: Suppose that $Z\subset Y$ is a smooth compact submanifold in a complex manifold $Y$  and let $p: X\to Y$ be given by the blow-up of $Y$ along $Z$. Then $p^{-1}(Z)$ has to be homologically nontrivial in $X$. Maybe this observation can be generalized to the setting of your question.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: Right. I suspect that, as in the blow-up example, the contracted locus of $f$ must have some  negativity property preventing it to be homologically trivial.

Comment: @MoisheKohan The Hopf torus is not a variety!

Comment: @DanPetersen: It depends on the terminology, some people refer to manifolds as varieties, this is how I read the comment. But maybe it was assumed to be a complete algebraic variety...

Comment: By variety I indeed meant an algebraic variety. (In French variety is used for a manifold, but I think this is quite rare in English.)

Comment: Also, I am not assuming that there is a fibre which is a curve: if $X$ is an algebraic variety then any positive dimensional subvariety contains an irreducible curve.

Comment: @naf Sorry, this means that I misread your comment.

Comment: When $f$ has degree $1$, this is proven in the paper (https://ppt.cc/fQjSCx), Theorem 2. Actually in their statement, they only assume equal second Betti number. If their result can be generalized to the case where the target is normal, then Stein factorization will allow to conclude.

Comment: @Faris: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for. There is a variation of Hironaka's example where the resulting manifold contains a line which is homologically equivalent to zero, see Appendix B, Example 3.4.2 of Hartshorne.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese then I wonder if there is a morphism that contracts that line.

Answer (score 4):

I think I've got it. This is only a sketch, and I am not an expert on singular complex analytic things, but it seems about right.

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a proper holomorphic map between complex manifolds of the same dimension $n$, and assume that some fiber has positive dimension. I want to find a rationally nontrivial element of the kernel of $f_\ast :H_{2k}(X)\to H_{2k}(Y)$ for some $k$.

Let $S\subset X$ be the union of all fibers having positive dimension. I presume that $S$ is a closed analytic subset of $X$. Let $Z$ be an irreducible component of $S$ of maximal dimension. Let $m$ be the dimension of $f(S)$. Let $k<n-m$ be the codimension of $Z$ in $X$. Choose a holomorphic map $j:D\to X$, where $D$ is the closed unit disk in $\mathbb C^k$, such that $j(0)\in Z$ and $j(D\backslash 0)\cap S=\emptyset$.

$f\circ j:D\to Y$ gives a relative $2k$-cycle for the pair $(Y,Y\backslash f(S))$, which I'll call $\Delta$. The $(2k-1)$-cycle $\partial \Delta$, given by the restriction of $f\circ j$ to the sphere $\partial D$, represents zero in $H_{2k-1}(Y\backslash f(S))$, because $H_{2k}(Y,Y\backslash f(S))=0$, because $2n-2m$, the (real) codimension of $f(S)$ in $Y$, is greater than $2k$. So there is a $2k$-chain $c$ in $Y\backslash f(S)$ with $\partial c=\partial\Delta $. In fact, the whole cycle $\Delta-c$ can be taken to be in a little ball, so that it is trivial in $H_{2k}(Y)$.

Because $f$ is finite to one over the complement of $f(S)$, we can arrange for $c$ to have a sort of branched cover, a chain $\tilde c$ in $X\backslash S$ whose boundary is a branched cover of $\partial\Delta$.

Now I want a chain $\tilde \Delta$ in $X$, an analytic chain that is a branched cover of $\Delta$ and has the same boundary as $\tilde c$. For this, make the fiber product of $f:X\to Y$ and $f\circ j:D\to Y$. In this fiber product let $\tilde D$ be the closure of the preimage of $D\backslash 0$. The resulting map $\tilde D\to X$ gives the desired $\tilde \Delta$.

The cycle $\tilde \Delta-\tilde c$ represents an element of $H_{2k}(X)$ which must have infinite order because its intersection number with the fundamental class of $Z$ is positive, because the only part of $\tilde \Delta-\tilde c$ that intersects $Z$ is the analytic part $\tilde \Delta$ (and it does intersect at least once, at $j(0)\in Z$).

Comment: I'm a little worried about the last sentence: Isn't it possible that $\tilde{\Delta}$ intersects $Z$ non-transversely and therefore may have zero intersection number?

Comment: If necessary we can choose for $j(0)$ to be a smooth point of $Z$ and choose for that intersection to be transverse.

Comment: But maybe the other intersection points of $\tilde\Delta$ and $Z$ can get me in trouble by not being isolated.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but does your argument prove that also the fundamental class of $Z$ is non-zero in homology (since there is a cycle having non-zero intersection with it)?

Comment: Yes, if my argument is correct (which I'm not sure of), then it also does what you say (if $X$ is compact).

Comment: So, were you assuming that $X$ is compact from the beginning?

Comment: If the restriction of $f$ to $ f^{-1}(Y\setminus f(S))\rightarrow Y\setminus f(S)$ is a covering map and the filling cycle c is chosen as a disk, then it seems one can lift c by using that a covering map induces injections on homotopy groups $\pi_{2k-1}$. Is your lift $\tilde{c}$ constructed by a generalization of this procedure? Or how do you lift $c$ to a "(branched) cover" $\tilde{c}$ in this easier situation of a covering over $Y\setminus f(S)$?